# Look at my code... How do expand to multiple categories?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

The following code works for one category - ID 9. How do I expand to two categories?

How shall I adjust to make it exclude category ID 9 AS WELL AS category ID 32?

```
<?php $showStartingAt = !$_product->isConfigurable() && $_product->getAttributeSetId() == 9 && $_product->getCategoryId() != 9; ?>
```

Comment: `<?php $showStartingAt = !$_product->isConfigurable() && $_product->getAttributeSetId() == 9 && ($_product->getCategoryId() != 9 ||$_product->getCategoryId() != 32); ?>` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing would be adding another comparison to the condition:

```
<?php $showStartingAt = !$_product->isConfigurable() && $_product->getAttributeSetId() == 9 && $_product->getCategoryId() != 9 && $_product->getCategoryId() != 32; ?>
```

A bit nicer and extendable would be something like:

```
<?php
$excludedCategories = array(9, 32); //Or other categories
$showStartingAt = !$_product->isConfigurable() && $_product->getAttributeSetId() == 9 && !in_array($_product->getCategoryId(), $excludedCategories); ?>
```

Comment: Wonderfully helpful - I can't thank you enough.